# Given the equation: $u^3t^2-2u^2tx+u(1+x^2)-1=0$ what does it imply when $t=3$.

Tags: calculus

Here we consider a one-dimensional approximation to a wave as it starts to overturn at a
beach. Let $u = u(x, t)$ denote the height of the free surface at position $x$ and time $t$ - in a
particular mathematical model it can be shown that $u$ satisfies the equation:
$$u^3t^2-2u^2tx+u(1+x^2)-1=0$$

What does it imply when $t=3$.

Ive looked at the state of the equation when $t=3$ but cant seem to see what it implies so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide context. "What it implies" is vague to the point of meaninglessness.

Comment: It implies that your given equation simplifies to $9u^3 - 6u^2x + u(1+x^2) - 1 =0$.

Comment: Well the context to the question is: 'Here we consider a one-dimensional approximation to a wave as it starts to overturn at a
beach. Let $u = u(x, t)$ denote the height of the free surface at position $x$ and time $t$ - in a
particular mathematical model it can be shown that $u$ satisfies the equation $u^3t^2-2u^2tx+u(1+x^2)-1=0$.' @Nick

Comment: @OPFragster That should go in the question. And that description already has the answer to your question.

Comment: How does it already have an answer? It still doesnt imply what $x$ or $u$ is @ThisIsNotAnId

Comment: Do you need to know what $x$ or $u$ is?

Comment: Int previous questions we got given an $x$ and $t$ value to find u but in this question they want to know what is implied when $t=3$, nothing else.@Kaynex

Comment: @OPFragster See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$u^3t^2-2u^2tx+u(1+x^2)-1=0$$ describes the surface tension $u$ in relation to the physical variables $x$ and $t$.

When you plug in $t=3$, you're looking at the state $u$ of the system for any given one-dimensional position $x$ along some pre-defined or assumed axis at time 3. Or you may assume that this is the surface tension of the wave at *one* particular arbitrary location $x$. That is, set $x$ to any valid value.

So, the way to use this equation is to first have some time and height you want to find the surface tension for. Or if you want to find out the positions and times at which a certain surface tension is possible, have at least one of the other two variables ($x$ and $t$) ready, unless you want a general equation.

Remember, this doesn't mean that any values you get out of this equation are valid. If you end up with negative or imaginary values for any three of the variables, for example, then they must be discarded.

I'm guessing this is from a Physics book. I guarantee you will find an application of this equation if they're not going over it in passing.

Finally, this question will get you a lot more insight on Physics.SE

Comment: [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

plugging $t=3$ in the given equation we get
$$9\,{u}^{3}-6\,{u}^{2}x+u \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) -1=0$$